# Bootstrap Inline Form on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make an [inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) for mobile viewport, such that the search button will be next to the input. But The documents said that

> This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

How can I achieve this results without using inline forms?

### Mobile Screen

**navbar-header**

[image: navbar-header]

Here's the navbar-header snippet: (Adding `.form-inline` in the form won't make it inline as the document mentioned)

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <!-- icon-bar span omitted -->
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

After searching through some of the bootstrap component, I can achieve what I want by thinking the form as an [input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) rather than as a form group.

[image: navbar-header]

Here's the snippet of my new navbar-header

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <!-- omitted icon-bar span -->
  </button>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>                
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```